# Deploying web application OpenShift Eclipse JBoss Tools

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7, openshift-client-tools, jboss-tools

For the first time I`m trying to deploy my web application on Openshift free hosting with JBoss Tools in Eclipse and nothing happens :)
my domain:
docs-velichko.rhcloud.com/
the end of my log when importing application:

```
    http://mirror.ops.rhcloud.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar (422 KB at 2600.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [SpringMVC6] in [/var/lib/openshift/55644f6ee0b8cd41470000de/app-root/runtime/repo/target/Mazurov20]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/var/lib/openshift/55644f6ee0b8cd41470000de/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [391 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /var/lib/openshift/55644f6ee0b8cd41470000de/app-root/runtime/repo/deployments/ROOT.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 38.069s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue May 26 07:22:48 EDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/131M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Preparing build for deployment
Deployment id is ae0b5aa5
Activating deployment
Starting MySQL 5.5 cartridge
Starting PHPMyAdmin cartridge
Starting jbossews cartridge
Found 127.10.169.129:8080 listening port
-------------------------
Git Post-Receive Result: success
Activation status: success
Deployment completed with status: success
```

when I`m trying to enter docs-velichko.rhcloud.com/, I see the wonderful "Welcome to your JBossEWS..." instead of my application.
In localhost my application works fine.
I hope somebody will help me. If this information is not enough, I will give you all information you need very quick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your maven build output shows that the war was deployed to /deployments which isnt the right folder. Deployment is the folder that wildfly app-servers pick their webapp-wars from. Tomcat/JBossEWS expect wars in webapps. We had a bug in older jboss tools versions where this error was occurring:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-15665

What version are you running? The above bug was fixed in JBoss Developer Studio 8 aka JBoss Tools 4.2.0.Final. Is this maybe causing your problem?
Tomcat manager, which is available at :8080/manager/html  should list you the deployed webapps and reflect your error, it should miss your webapp.

Cheers, André

Comment: Solved! You were right! I`m was running Eclipse Keppler, and system advised me to install the optimal JBoss Tools version fo Keppler, which is older than 4.2.0 FINAL. That caused my troubles... Installation of JBoss Tools 4.2.3 on Eclipse Luna solved my problem! Very big thank you!